# How to combine multiple dataframes by selecting specific columns when the column names are different

Tags: r, dataframe, rbind

I have seven data.frames within a list `my_data`. Three of these data.frames have 16 columns, the other four have 22 columns. There are five columns in each data.frame that I need to bind into one data.frame (`all_data`). The problem is that I can't simply select the columns I want to retain by name, because the names are different (but similar) between each data.frame, and in different orders. For example, I have one data.frame that has a column titled "X2012.NAICS.code" and one that has a column titled "X2007.NAICS.codes.and.NAICS.based.rollup.code". These columns contain the same info (NAICS codes) and need to be bond together.
The approach I am trying to use is this:

```
header_cols <- c( "Geographic.area.name", "Year", "**3rd column**", "**4th column**", "**5th column**" )

all_data <- map_dfr( my_data[grepl( "^ASM", names( my_data ))], ~ 
                               .x %>%
                               select( header_cols ))
```

Where the 3rd, 4th, and 5th columns are the three others I need (`Year` and `Geographic.area.name` are the same between all 7 data.frames).

All data.frame names begin with "ASM", which is what the `^ASM` is for.

UPDATE: My current strategy is this

```
# Make object for raw column name strings (all columns of interest contain these strings in all dataframes)
name_pattern <- c( "Geographic.area.name", "Geographic Area Name")
VoS_pattern <- c( "Total.value.of.shipment", "value of shipments")
NAICS_pattern <- c( "NAICS.code", "NAICS code")
industry_pattern <- c("Meaning.of.", "Meaning of NAICS code")
relative_pattern <- c("Relative.standard.error", "Relative standard error")
header_cols <- c( "Year" )

# Part 3: binding the data into one dataframe based on the columns of interest, uniting columns that contain the same information category
# Bind the columns of interest into one dataframe
combined_data <- map_dfr( my_data[grepl( "^ASM", names( my_data ))], ~
                            .x %>%
                            select( header_cols, contains( paste0( name_pattern ) ),
                                    contains( paste0( VoS_pattern ) ),
                                    contains( paste0( NAICS_pattern ) ),
                                    contains( paste0( industry_pattern ) ),
                                    -contains ( paste0( relative_pattern) ) ))
```

which works perfectly. Unfortunately, I can't use the `map_dfr` function (or any function specific to purrr, so am looking for a way to do this with rbind.

Comment: What are the names of 3rd, 4th, 5th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to standardize the column names with `rename_at` after `select`ing the columns.

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
library(purrr)
map_dfr(my_data[grep('^ASM', names(my_data))], ~ 
     .x %>%
       select(header_cols[1:2], 
            matches("NAICS\\.(code|based\\.rollup\\.code)")) %>%
       rename_at(matches("NAICS"), ~ str_remove(., "^X\\d{4}\\.")))
```

---

Or with `base R` using `lapply`

```
v1 <- c("Year", "state_name", "VoS_thousUSD", "NAICS_code", "industry")

out <- lapply(my_data[grep('^ASM', names(my_data))],
       function(x) x %>%
           mutate_if(is.factor, as.character) %>%
          select( header_cols, contains( paste0( name_pattern ) ),
                  contains( paste0( VoS_pattern ) ),
                  contains( paste0( NAICS_pattern ) ),
                 contains( paste0( industry_pattern ) ),
                -contains ( paste0( relative_pattern) ) ) %>% 
                set_names(v1))

combined_data <- do.call(rbind, out)
row.names(combined_data) <- NULL


# Make VoS numeric
combined_data_new <- combined_data %>%
        dplyr::mutate( VoS_thousUSD = as.numeric( VoS_thousUSD ) )
```

Comment: What do you mean by "location"? The location of the columns varies by data.frame- a column of interest could be column 11 in  one data.frame, and the corresponding column could be column 21 in another.

Comment: @MarideeWeber. okay, I was looking at tyour `"**3rd column**", "**4th column**", "**5th column**"` and thought that it is the specific location in the data.frtame

Comment: @MarideeWeber i updated the post.  Not clear about the patterns for 3rd to 5th columnnames.  It was based on the info you provided in the post

Comment: would you know how to accomplish this without the use of map_dfr? It's a function that isn't in our datasystem, and installing new packages (we don't use purrr) is a no-no. I'm updating the question with what I'm currently doing as well.

Comment: @MarideeWeber  Sure, you can use `lapply` from `base R` `do.call(rbind, lapply(my_data[grep('^ASM', names(my_data))], function(x) x %>% ..`

Comment: I tried this and got ```Error in match.names(clabs, names(xi)) : 
  names do not match previous names```

Comment: @MarideeWeber  If there are different columns and different column names in the `list`, `map` or `rbindlist` (from `data.table`  with `fill = TRUE`) will automatically pick up those and change the rest of the rows to NA, but in `rbind`, it won't happen

Comment: @MarideeWeber  Can you change those column names to same one (as there is no reproducible example, I can't test your code)

Comment: Sorry, I am not quite following. There are different columns and different column names in almost all of the dataframes in the ```list```. I am trying to change the column names (only of the columns I want to appear in the new dataframe) , so that I can then rbind them.

Comment: @MarideeWeber Can you show the `str(my_data[grep('^ASM', names(my_data))])`

Comment: @MarideeWeber I understand, what I meant is that suppose, your list is `my_data <- list(data.frame(col1 = 1:5), data.frame(col2 = 1:5), data.frame(col3 = 1:5))` these are different column names and `rbind` won't work with that.  If you are sure those column names should be the same, then you can subset the data and change the column names to a common one and then `rbind` should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215768/discussion-between-maridee-weber-and-akrun).

Comment: @MarideeWeber i.e. in the example I showed above `v1 <- "newcol"; do.call(rbind, lapply(my_data, setNames, v1))`